# Vue.js - function not executed when data are updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dexie

I have this function code in my vue component methods that will remove the customers data if a button is clicked and show a chrome notification.

```
        deleteCustomer(id) {
            console.log('deleting customer:' + id);
            db.customers.delete(id).then( () => {
            console.log('customer '+ id +' deleted!');
            browser.notifications.create('deleted',{
                type: 'basic',
                iconUrl: 'icons/128.png',
                title: 'Data removal',
                message: 'data removed with success!'
            });
            this.viewCustomers();
           });
        },
```

At the end of the function I'm calling another method that is supposed to call a dexie.js instance to show in a table all the customers data that are stored. When the component is mounted, all work fine with the `viewCustomers` function and the table is populated correctly. What I need to fix is that the method is not called after data deletion and the table isn't updating. How I can fix this, is there a vue function I can use or any code modification that can solve this problem?

Comment: `db.customers.delete` is this a async call?

Comment: here is the docs https://dexie.org/docs/API-Reference#delete-items ,it will give an example where is used the await keyword, probably it's async.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the docs, [Delete items](https://dexie.org/docs/API-Reference#delete-items) is actually an async call which means it calls the `this.viewCustomers()` before the item is even deleted, thus it seems that it is not working. The easiest way to resolve this is to use async/await like:

```
async deleteCustomer(id) {
  console.log('deleting customer:' + id);
  await db.customers.delete(id);
  console.log('customer ' + id + ' deleted!');
  browser.notifications.create('deleted', {...});
  this.viewCustomers();
},
```

Now, the `this.viewCustomers` the function will be only called once the `db.customers.delete()` function is completed and that should result in the desired output.

Comment: I've added a then after the `.delete()` function is called. The notification is displayed but the function isn't executed. I will update the code as you've suggested. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please updated your code to show how have you added `then` and the viewCustomers inside `then`. Also, please explain what you mean by `the function isn't executed.`. Do you mean, if you put a console log inside viewCustomers that is not displayed?

Comment: Testing the code but not working as expected, the notification stopped working :(

Comment: @palash I've updated the code with the `then`. For the function `this.viewCustomers()` I mean that isn't called after the data deletion and the table will show always the old data

Comment: have you tried to use a `debugger` keyword to see what is happening inside the `then` callback?

Comment: no, didn't tried. I'm using the `.each` method of dexie https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.each() to display the data stored, I don't think that this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After some headche I've found a tricky solution that will give me the ability to update the table with the updated data. I've used the `onClicked` method of `chrome.notifications` API and now all works fine, but I'm opened to every suggestion about this problem.
Here is the code I've added in the mounted section of vue instance:

```
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted')
        this.$set(this, 'isActive', true)
        this.viewCustomers()
        browser.notifications.onClosed.addListener( (notificationId) => {
            console.log(notificationId)
            this.customersList = [];
            this.viewCustomers();
        })
    }
```